# pandas: melt 100+ variables into 100+ new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, automation, melt

Pretty new to stackoverflow, please bear with me if the format looks odd..

I have a big set of data with 100+ columns of data structured like:

countrya countryb year variable1 variable2 ...... varaible100

I want to have the 100 variables separated into 100 new dataframes and save them into csvs.

Below is the code I have for creating 1 new csv.

```
dfm1=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['countrya','countryb','year'], value_vars=['variable1'],
         value_name='variable1')
dfm1.drop('variable',axis=1)
dfm1.to_csv('newdf1.csv')
```

How  can I automate the process?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.  First, create the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country_a': [1, 2, 3],
    'country_b': [4, 5, 6],
    'year': [2018, 2019, 2020],
    'var_a': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'var_b': ['x', 'y', 'z']
})

print(df)
   country_a  country_b  year var_a var_b
0          1          4  2018     a     x
1          2          5  2019     b     y
2          3          6  2020     c     z
```

Second, iterate over the fields with your column names.

```
base_fields = df.columns[:3].to_list()    # columns in every file
var_fields = df.columns[3:]               # var_a, var_b, ...

for var_field in var_fields:
    file_name = f'{var_field}.csv'
    with open(file_name, 'wt') as handle:
        fields = base_fields + [var_field]
        df.loc[:, fields].to_csv(handle)
        
        print(f'wrote {fields} to {file_name}')


wrote ['country_a', 'country_b', 'year', 'var_a'] to var_a.csv
wrote ['country_a', 'country_b', 'year', 'var_b'] to var_b.csv
                                          ^              ^
                                          last field and file name change
```

Comment: this completely solves my question! Thanks so much!!!!!!

Comment: Do you mind if I ask a followup question?  I'm trying to melt all the new CSVs. The code I have for melt is: table=pd.pivot_table(var_a, values='var_a', index=['countrya','countryb'],columns=['year']) table1=table.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)... Finding a hard time automate the process again!

Comment: Please can you post this as a new question, and include both actual input data and desired output?  (It seems too involved for a comment.). This SO post may be helpful for creating the input data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424537/13608599

Comment: Hi I posted in this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601469/separate-dataframe-into-multiple-new-dataframes-and-bulk-retructure-the-new-dfs

Comment: Hi, I just posted my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop against all variables, and call your function inside it(assuming your sample code is correct)

```
def split(df, variable_name):
  dfm1=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['countrya','countryb',variable_name], value_vars=[variable_name], value_name=variable_name)
  dfm1.drop('variable',axis=1) # I don't know what's this line used for
  dfm1.to_csv('newdf_{}.csv'.format(variable_name))

for variable_name in ['variable1', 'variable2']:
  split(df, variable_name)
```

Comment: when I melt the df, it gives me a 'variable' column with all same values of my variable names. dfm1.drop('variable',axis=1) is to delete the 'variable' column..                              Tried to run it and got this error: ValueError: arrays must all be same length